# MySQL Syntax Error

Tags: sql, mysql

I am getting this error when I try to run this MySQL command:

```
CREATE TABLE READERWARE(TITLE VARCHAR_IGNORECASE NOT NULL,
AUTHOR VARCHAR_IGNORECASE NOT NULL,
ISBN CHAR,
PUBLISHER VARCHAR_IGNORECASE,
BOOKFORMAT CHAR,
FIRST CHAR,
SIGNED CHAR,
PUBDATE VARCHAR_IGNORECASE,
PUBPLACE VARCHAR_IGNORECASE,
COPIES CHAR,
RATING INTEGER,
CONDITION INTEGER,
CATEGORY INTEGER,
READ CHAR,
PRINT CHAR,
HTMLEXPORT CHAR,
VALUE CHAR,
COMMENTS VARCHAR_IGNORECASE,
DATEENTERED DATE NOT NULL,
SOURCE CHAR,
ROWKEY BIGINT NOT NULL,
RETIRED1 CHAR,
CART CHAR,
ORDERED CHAR,
LCCN VARCHAR_IGNORECASE,
DEWEY VARCHAR_IGNORECASE,
USERNUMBER VARCHAR_IGNORECASE,
COPYRIGHTDATE VARCHAR_IGNORECASE,
VALUEDATE VARCHAR_IGNORECASE,
LOCATION INTEGER,
SERIES INTEGER,
PAGES INTEGER,
KEYWORDS VARCHAR_IGNORECASE,
DIMENSIONS VARCHAR_IGNORECASE,
USER1 VARCHAR_IGNORECASE,
USER2 VARCHAR_IGNORECASE,
USER3 VARCHAR_IGNORECASE,
USER4 VARCHAR_IGNORECASE,
USER5 VARCHAR_IGNORECASE,
USER6 VARCHAR_IGNORECASE,
USER7 VARCHAR_IGNORECASE,
USER8 VARCHAR_IGNORECASE,
USER9 VARCHAR_IGNORECASE,
USER10 VARCHAR_IGNORECASE,
FILLER1 VARCHAR_IGNORECASE,
FILLER2 VARCHAR_IGNORECASE,
FILLER3 VARCHAR_IGNORECASE,
FILLER4 VARCHAR_IGNORECASE,
FILLER5 VARCHAR_IGNORECASE,
FILLER6 VARCHAR_IGNORECASE,
FILLER7 VARCHAR_IGNORECASE,
FILLER8 VARCHAR_IGNORECASE,
FILLER9 VARCHAR_IGNORECASE,
FILLER10 VARCHAR_IGNORECASE,
AUTHOR2 VARCHAR_IGNORECASE,
AUTHOR3 VARCHAR_IGNORECASE,
AUTHOR4 VARCHAR_IGNORECASE,
AUTHOR5 VARCHAR_IGNORECASE,
AUTHOR6 VARCHAR_IGNORECASE)


Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VARCHAR_IGNORECASE NOT NULL,AUTHOR VARCHAR_IGNORECASE NOT NULL,ISBN CHAR,PUBLISH' at line 1
```

I'm not sure what the problem is.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Please, read up on SQL database normalization.  It's good stuff.  Also, you need a primary key for the table.  Also, don't upper-case your column names.  Also, MySQL has types other than `VARCHAR` and `INTEGER` - like, for instance, a `DATE`.  Which your `COPYRIGHTDATE` should be.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Err, I think the problem is that MySQL [doesn't actually have](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-types.html) a VARCHAR_IGNORECASE type.

HSQL from OpenOffice has it but I've not seen it used elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

`VARCHAR_IGNORECASE` is not a valid datatype in `MySQL`.

If you want case-insensitive text fields with arbitrary length, replace these types with `TEXT COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI`